# Detection of Zeeman effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

If the the external magnetic field is along Z direction and we put Znic atom in this field, we can get circular polarization from anti-Z direction, and the linear polarization from the vertical Z direction.
I am wondering the **method** to detect the polarization from the **vertical** Z direction?

Comment: What do you mean by the "anti-z" direction?

Comment: Thanks for your attention! By "anti-z" I mean "from the oppsite of Z-direction".

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question but I think the answer is if one puts a plane polarisation filter in the light path and observe if there is an image and then turn filter 90 degrees. If light only shows in one of the two angles it’s plane. If both then the light is circular polarised.